# Querying a one to one relationship from a collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

The problem is I need to pull a collection from a collection. I have already set up the models and database so these relationships work:

A User can have many Negotiations

A Negotiation has one RiderNegotiation

However I can't perform this query:

```
$user->negotiations->riderNegotiation
```

I thought I could get around this in my view file if I just passed off $user->negotiation and then parse through the negotiations. I discovered I can't use isEmpty() this way however.

```
@if($negotiations->riderNegotiation->isEmpty()
```

Is there some kind of nifty trick in Laravel to do this kind of relationship querying? I feel like this is a common issue.

Comment: try is_null($negotiations->riderNegotiation)

Comment: @AyobamiOpeyemi that will not work because $negotiations is a collection and the method ->riderNegotiation will not work on it. If $negotiations was a model it would work.

There has to be a way to get a collection of riderNegotiations from a user, because they are only separated by 1 relation. I'm just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

hasMany returns a Collection of elements and you can't call hasOne on a Collection.
You should be able to do:

```
 $negociations = User::find(1)->negotiations;
 @foreach($negociations as $negociation)
    echo get_class($negociation->riderNegotiation); //riderNegotiation
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$negotiations = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->negotiations;

    $temp = array();

    foreach($negotiations as $negotiation ) {


        $temp = array_merge($temp,$negotiaton->riderNegotiation->toArray());
    };
```

A little resource expensive but $temp should contain all rider negotiations for that user.

Comment: This answer seems overcomplicated and a bit clunky. -1

Comment: I think the answer lies within Eager Loading with constraints